# table creation with multiple column

Tags: tables

I have to create a table similar to this:
[image]

my problem is in creating the leftmost colum, My attempt is this:

```
\begin{table}
           \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
     \caption{\emph{{Assegnazione dei chemical shifts}}
        \hline
        Unità & Assegnazioni & $\delta - ^1$ H (ppm) & $\delta - ^{13}$C (ppm) \\
        \hline
        \multirow{6}{*}{Ramnosio-3-solfato-Glucuronico} & R1 & 4.81 & 101.14\\
        & R2 & 4.28 & 68.92 \\
        & R3 & 4.65 & 78.68 \\
        & R4 & 3.83 & 71.45\\
        & R5 & 4.08 & 67.94\\
        & R6(CH$_3$) & 1.27 & 16.57\\ 

        \hline

        \multirow{6}{*}{Ramnosio-3-solfato-Iduronico} & R’1 & 4.80 & 99.78 \\
        & R’2 & 4.27 & 68.91 \\
        & R’3 &  4.68 &  78.29\\
        & R’4 & 3.84 & 75.95 \\
        & R’5 & 4.11 & 67.55\\
        & R’6(CH$_3$) & 1.34 & 16.76

        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which solved the issue. I need just a caption now 'cause I get:

> LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is certainly *possible* to recreate the "look" of the screenshot you posted by using `\multirow` statements -- see the code and the left-hand part of the screenshot below for an example -- I'd like to encourage you to move away from this not- particularly-appealing approach toward creating a table.

As the example on the right-hand side of the screenshot demonstrates, one can create a much more aesthetically appealing table by omitting all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, using the macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining few horizontal lines and, yes, not using `\multirow`. It's simply not necessary to shift the words "Glucoronic" and "Iduronico" down in order for people to understand how the table "works".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Unit{\`a} & Assegnazioni \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Glucoronico}
   & R1 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R2 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R3 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R4 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R5 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R6 \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Iduronico}
   & R'1 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R'2 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R'3 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R'4 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R'5 \\ \cline{2-2}
   & R'6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{1cm}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lc @{}}
\toprule
Unit{\`a} & Assegnazioni \\ 
\midrule
Glucoronico
   & R1 \\
   & R2 \\
   & R3 \\
   & R4 \\
   & R5 \\ 
   & R6 \\ 
\midrule
Iduronico
   & R'1 \\
   & R'2 \\
   & R'3 \\
   & R'4 \\
   & R'5 \\
   & R'6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: To create a caption, encase the `tabular` environment in a `table` environment and add a `\caption{...}` statement. Depending on whether you want the caption to be above or below the tabular material, the `\caption` statement should come either right before or right after the `tabular` environment. In the following example, the caption is placed above the tabular material.

I would also like to suggest that you (a) use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, (b) use the `\ce` macro of the `mhchem` package to typeset chemical formulas, (c) use the facilities of the `siunitx` package to align numbers in a column on their decimal markers, and (d) use math-mode to typeset the material in the second column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % optional, but recommended
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx,mhchem}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % left-aligned col., automatic math mode
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{\dots}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} lLcS[table-format=3.2] @{}}
\toprule
Unità & $Assegnazioni$ & $\delta$-\ce{^{1}H} & {$\delta$-\ce{^{13}C}} \\
& & (ppm) & {(ppm)}\\
\midrule
Ramnosio-3-solfato-Glucuronico 
& R_1 & 4.81 & 101.14\\
& R_2 & 4.28 & 68.92 \\
& R_3 & 4.65 & 78.68 \\
& R_4 & 3.83 & 71.45\\
& R_5 & 4.08 & 67.94\\
& R_6\ (\ce{CH3}) & 1.27 & 16.57\\
\midrule
Ramnosio-3-solfato-Iduronico
& R'_1 & 4.80 & 99.78 \\
& R'_2 & 4.27 & 68.91 \\
& R'_3 & 4.68 & 78.29 \\
& R'_4 & 3.84 & 75.95 \\
& R'_5 & 4.11 & 67.55 \\
& R'_6\ (\ce{CH3}) & 1.34 & 16.76\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great can you show me also how to add a caption?

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: it seems that there is a runaway argument:Runaway argument?
{\emph {{Assegnazione dei c.s. $^1$H e $^{13}$C delle risonanze dell'\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta - Two comments. First, I strongly recommend using the `\ce` macro (of the `mhchem` package) to typeset chemical formulas. Second, I'm afraid I don't understand why you write `\emph{{`. `\emph{` should suffice.

Comment: @Mico A great and comprehensive response. I always wish you the best.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Many thanks for the compliment!